# Greenplum COPY not filtering duplicate entries

Tags: copy, primary-key, greenplum

I have a problem loading contents to the green plum table using COPY command. What i have is three column table lets say A , B , C and the table should not entertain duplicate elements. So i have made a composite key clubbing the above three

```
PRIMARY KEY ( A , B , C )
```

But the input file which I am using to load the table, has duplicate entries. All I want is, the COPY command to filter off the duplicate elements and continue loading the data. But in my case whenever the COPY encounters a duplicate entry, it aborts the loading. Any leads on how to proceed??

Thanks

Ganesh.R

Answer (score 1):

COPY doesn't work like that.

The first thing I'd try is the system sort.

```
sort -u old_filename > new_filename
```

The '-u' argument tells `sort` to output only unique lines.

Comment: On SO, we express thanks by upvotes and by accepting answers. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/161666 Although you haven't asked many questions, you also haven't accepted any answers yet. On SO, that tends to make people less willing to help you in the future.